# How can I mellow the taste of this goat cheese

Tags: cheese, goat

Two days ago, I bought a goat cheese. It looked white and rectangular, it didn't had a particular name, and because it was in plastic I couldn't smell it. I got home, opened it, and wrapped it in paper.

Some time after, I took a bite, and the cheese's texture was already not as expected; not creamy, kinda hard, and without a layer around. I took a bite and it felt like licking a ram. I tried to mitigate it with bread, and left it alone. Later, I gave it another round; this time on toasted bread, hoping cooking it would get the stench out of it. It didn't work. Now, i tried to crush it and mix it with olive oil and rosemary; it didn't work.

I want to know what I can do to mellow out the taste of the cheese to a level I can enjoy.

[image]

EDIT: In this specific case, the taste was due to the shepherd not separating the goats from the rams. Didn't knew that, but if you do this, the ram's hormones, essence, will impart on the milk, and the resulting cheese. There's nothing to do about it.

Comment: Not having ever licked a ram before I'm struggling to imagine what you're describing ... ;)

Comment: @brhans salty (a lot!) smelly. If you close your eyes you find yourself grazing in a mountain with your fellow horizontal-pupiled folks

Comment: Exactly what is it that you would like to know?  I am not sure what your question is.

Comment: Hello and welcome! I'm not really sure what you are asking. It sounds like you simply don't like the cheese. Not sure how we can help with that.

Comment: @Cindy Hi! I would like to know how could i accomodate, cook, or prepare this cheese so that i could appreaciate it. By lowering its very strong taste, or maybe put it with something that would make the taste seem more normal ? thanks

Comment: What country is that ? maybe it will help us help you ?

Comment: @Max would a photo be helfpful ? if the country is important to you, assume it' s italy

Comment: yes, a photo might help, and maybe what region.

Comment: I once had some cheese that tasted incredibly strong - it was not meant to be like this, it had a contaminant bacterium that I can't for the life of me recall or find using google. We unsuccessfully tried all sorts to get it to a point where it was more palatable. Just saying, that cheeses that don't taste good aren't necessarily meant to taste that way!

Comment: The only person who could possibly answer this question is yourself. No one else will ever know how this cheese tastes or how to "fix it" to your liking.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried anything involving cooking the cheese?

I have a feeling that some of the goatiest (not a word but it should be) goat's cheese is mellowed a little by heat. You could try thin slices on (part of) a pizza, or warming it, pressing it onto toast and finishing under a grill or with a blowtorch. The usual accompaniment to that would be a green salad including some strongly flavoured (peppery or bitter) leaves, which would also compete with the flavour.

Comment: I only just went for making this an answer rather than a comment, as I haven't tried the cheese in question or cooking with it myself.

Comment: i take note, the pizza seem like a good idea. For now i only tried to put it on a toast on a pan, with a cover. It melted a little, i added pepper but didn't really worked

Comment: +1 for the heat. I don't like the smell of goat cheese, definitely smells like a sheep to me but i have found goat cheese melted on pizza or tarts arevery nice, no strong smell and tastes quite mellow. Use a small amount mixed in with other strong flavours as Chris said, like a pear and walnut tart with some cheese in it on a puff pastry base.

Answer (score 3):

This looks, and sounds, like a feta style cheese. I know that people are accustomed to seeing a certain type of cheese as "goat cheese", but goat milk can be used in mostly every type of cheese as cow or sheep milk.

You can try leaving it for several days in water in a closed box in the fridge, and see if it reduces the smell to a level you like. If necessary, change the water a few times. This is normally done with feta to reduce the salt, but will also dilute the aroma somewhat.

It is not certain whether you can ever take it to a taste level which you personally enjoy, for background see [I overseasoned my food, what can I do to remove the strong smell?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/95243/i-overseasoned-my-food-what-can-i-do-to-remove-the-strong-smell).

Comment: This sound like an extremely good Idea. I'll try it when i get home

Comment: Perhaps slice it first to get the salt out faster by increasing the contact with the water

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try it with a tapenade on some toast points, or melt it into a bechamel and pour atop some charred artichoke hearts and serve with some preparation of beef.

If you go the cheese sauce route, you may think about cutting the bold goat cheese with something a little blander, like an Emmental or Muenster or mild cheddar.

Answer (score 0):

I would say aromatic herbs such as thyme, rosemary, laurel leaves and spices such as curry, ginger and ground white or black pepper should give goat cheese a refreshing twist and mellow its gamey flavor. I have goat’s cheese in my fridge which I am planning to use in my healthy experimental bread with pockets of spicy cheese.