# Burnt milk uses

Tags: milk, culinary-uses

Though infrequently, when boiling milk, it gets burnt if you forget about the milk on stove.
I usually boil 2-3L of milk in one big pan on stove/induction.
When it gets burnt, it develops a peculiar smell and taste and in our house nobody can bear it.
Even if I make curd or cottage cheese from that milk, they all have that burnt flavour.
Hence I have to throw that whole quantity of milk.

Hence, is there anyway of removing that bad burnt flavour or else, utilising that flavoured milk into something which can be consumed by us?

Comment: You can turn burnt milk into something edible, you just need to wait a year : throw it into a compost bin. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are certainly culinary uses for burnt milk.  You could make [burnt milk ice cream](https://chefjet.com/recipe/burnt-milk-ice-cream-recipe/), or [burnt milk pudding](https://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/1017927-turkish-burned-milk-pudding-kazandibi). The second link is from the NYTimes, in case it is paywall protected, [here is another example](https://edibleottawa.ediblecommunities.com/recipes/burnt-milk-pudding-rice).  It might be worth an experiment to see if it is to your liking.

Comment: +1 because it shows that the taste can be enjoyed.

Answer (score 10):

I'm sorry, but there are no good news here.

First, you cannot remove the flavor. Whatever you do, the flavor stays there. ([This question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/95243/i-overseasoned-my-food-what-can-i-do-to-remove-the-strong-smell) goes into more detail about why you can't remove flavors).

Second, there are no culinary uses for it. Of course you can do stuff with it - turn it into yogurt, cheese, etc. But see point one: the flavor will still be there. So you will hate whatever you make out of it for the same reason you hated the milk in the first place.

Comment: There are some smoked or very smelly cheeses, wouldn’t it work for those?

Comment: @Michael the smell won't disappear. There might be people whose perception is so distracted by the cheese smell that the burnt-milk-smell becomes less salient, but it is impossible to predict for whom this effect will be sufficiently large to start enjoying the cheese - and we are biased towards paying a lot of attention to unpleasant smells, so 1) it is likely that for most people, the smell of burnt will come through, and 2) the effect of "cheese smell covers burnt smell" is most likely to occur for those who hate smelly cheese. It doesn't stop you from trying, if you feel like it.

Comment: It's not just about “covering up” but about _expectations_, that it depends a lot on context how good or bad some particular flavour note is perceived. If you expect a “fresh, clean” tasting cottage cheese then a burnt note is quickly off-putting. If you expect something from the barbeque?

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to remove the flavour of burned milk once it's reached that point. That being said, even though it's not edible you could probably try to salvage it into some sort of a like beauty thing or an art project with some flour.

And if all else fails, you could probably reuse it as fertilizer in your garden rather than pouring it away into the sink.

Answer (score 1):

...not sure if this relates to your question, but i would use it as a shower rinse or a bath soak maybe with a dash of honey... ancient Egyptian spa treatment for the whole family...*just rinse well after ;) hmmmmm yumm

Comment: But if they can't bear the smell of it... imagine having that smell all over your body for hours!